# Color a bloc text to make it look like the French flag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a given bloc of text in a webpage, and I want to make it look like the French flag (Blue / White / Red) using javascript and JQuery.

Right now I tried the following code : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nwmopg3/2/)

Or if you're more into Stackoverflow snippets :

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  // Calculates the text width in <p>
 var html_cur = $('.loremipsum').html();
 var html_calc = '<span>' + html_cur + '</span>';
 $('.loremipsum').html(html_calc);
 var width = $('.loremipsum').find('span:first').width(); 
  
 var color_width = Math.floor(width / 3), // Width of each color
  text = $( ".loremipsum" ).text(), // Text of <p>
  array = [], // Array containing each sentences 
  sentence = '', // Current sentence
  sentence_width = 0; // Current sentence width

 for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
   // Gets the char in the text
  var char = text[i];
  
    // Calulates actual char's width in pixels
  var html_calc = '<span>' + char + '</span>';
  $('.loremipsum').html(html_calc);
  var width = $('.loremipsum').find('span:first').width();
  
    // Apply to variables
  sentence_width += width;
  sentence += char;

  // If sentence is long enough, 
    // resets the variables to start a new sentence and add it to the array
    // Added the -10 to make sure sentences never overflow the color_width
    // but looks like it's not enough
  if(sentence_width >= color_width - 10) {
   array.push(sentence);
   sentence = '';
   sentence_width = 0;
  }
 }

 // Variables for final html
 var final_html = '',
  color = 0;

 // Loops through the sentences and add them in between the correct color
 final_html = '<span class="color-0">';
 for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
  final_html += array[i];
  color = (color == 2) ? 0 : color + 1;
  final_html += '</span><span class="color-'+color+'">';
 }
 final_html += '</span>';

 // Display text on screen
 $('.loremipsum').html(final_html);
});
```

```css
.loremipsum {
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 12px;
  width: 300px;
}

.color-0 {
 color : blue;
}

.color-1 {
 color : white;
}

.color-2 {
 color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="loremipsum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

So basically the routine is as follows:

1. Calculate the width of the text in the p element, and divide it by 3 to get how wide each color should be.
2. Split the text into sentences, which will be stocked into an array. Each sentence should have its width equal to or a bit inferior to a color's width. This is done by iterating through the chars in the text, and calculate the width of each character to know when to split the text into a new sentence.
3. Generate the final text for the p element. Meaning encapsulating each sentence within a span element with the appropriate color (blue, white, red, repeat).

Problem is, sentences tend to be a bit longer than what they should be, so the color changes too lately, resulting in an offset increasing at each new line.

Does anyone have any idea to make this look like an actual BLUE/WHITE/RED text bloc?

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: Non supported yet but for further reference the *background-clip* https://jsfiddle.net/8nwmopg3/3/

Comment: The best thing for this would be using a monospace font (Courier New or Consolas, for instance). The browser doesn't tell JS how wide each letter is, so it has no way of judging this unless it knows already (and that is a lot of measuring and math...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using @DaniP 's comment

He sets a [background gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) using css and then applies it to the text via [-webkit-background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

```css
body { background-color: lightgray; } /* Just for easier viewing */
.loremipsum {
  font-size: 15px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0, mediumblue 33.3%, white 33.3%, white 66.6%, red 66.6%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p class="loremipsum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: mix-blend-mode could also help http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rMXVbP inspired from http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZWMxdL ;) (works in FF too )

Comment: No idea why I didn't think about it. Thanks a lot. :)